# handle large PHP strings

Tags: php, soap, split, large-data

I have a PHP (soap call) which returns a total of 472.059 characters

all the valuable data is comma seperated (the entire file)

how should I proceed.

exploding seems to take its time

the explode then again should be chunked

(copy pasted in word)

pages 210

words 7821

characters 472.059

Comment: Save directly to disk, then read and process a line at a time using fgetcsv()

Comment: 500K characters ? Not big enough ...

Comment: Do you need all 472059 characters, for sure?